# Legends for line charts in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'd like to customize a legend for line data so that the legend graphic is a line (styled like the actually data line) rather than a box.

As far as I can tell [from the source](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/0dccc85e3a0f6a9e2fa2cb6e4c39533dcbc653d5/src/core/core.legend.js), the graphic can be a point or a box, and the height of the box is fixed to the font size.  The 'generateLabels' option does not seem to allow for extending around these contraints.

Version 2.2.1.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 18):

#### NOTE: This solution only works if you have a local version of Chart.js since it needs to edit a function in the source code of the library, which can't be done if you import it form a CDN.

To achieve what you want, you will need to edit the `drawLegendBox` function (*[link to source here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/plugins/plugin.legend.js#L353)*).

First, as if you wanted to do a pointStyle legend, add the `useLineStyle` and set it to `true` like this :

```js
options: {
    legend: {
        labels : {
            useLineStyle: true
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to go to your local version of Chart.js (*obvisouly, you cannot edit it if you import it from a CDN*) and search for the function `drawLegendBox` (on Chart.js v2.2.1, it is roughly line 6460; in Chart.js v2.9.4 search for `labelOpts && labelOpts.usePointStyle`).

Scroll down a little bit to see something like this :

```js
if (opts.labels && opts.labels.usePointStyle) {
    // Recalulate x and y for drawPoint() because its expecting
    // x and y to be center of figure (instead of top left)
    var radius = fontSize * Math.SQRT2 / 2;
    var offSet = radius / Math.SQRT2;
    var centerX = x + offSet;
    var centerY = y + offSet;

    // Draw pointStyle as legend symbol
    Chart.canvasHelpers.drawPoint(ctx, legendItem.pointStyle, radius, centerX, centerY);
}
// --- NEW CONDITION GOES HERE ---
else {
    // Draw box as legend symbol
    ctx.strokeRect(x, y, boxWidth, fontSize);
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, boxWidth, fontSize);
}
```

And add this between the two conditions :

```js
else if (opts.labels && opts.labels.useLineStyle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y + fontSize * 0.45);
    ctx.lineTo(x + boxWidth, y + fontSize * 0.45);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

With this edit, everytime you will set `useLineStyle` to true, legend boxes will be drawn as lines, as the following screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tektiv.  I'd like to keep this open to see if there's a way to do it without forking the library.  Appreciate this answer.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you are unable to edit the source? I have chartjs installed via npm in an angular application and this answer, while excellent, isnt an option for me.

Comment: @Dave It has been a while since I have used Chart.js though I think there is still now way to do it without digging in the source code. You could host your own version of Chart.js on a server and import it later as you do with npm

Comment: There is still no option in version 2.7.1, but tektiv's code still works. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to use pointStyle: `line`, in the dataset and then under options use labels: `{usePointStyle: true,}`,

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! I don't know why this was so difficult to find

Comment: Ok this works, but now the points are not shown as circles anymore ...

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER GUYS, Thanks dude

Answer (score 4):

### `chart.js` v3

For this version, none of the previously mentioned built-in configurations work. You can set `boxHeight: 0` on the legend labels in order to get a line instead of a box:

```js
{
  legend: {
    labels: {
      boxHeight: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to improve on this solution from tektiv.
If you want to show a dashed line too use this code in the same spot.

(chartJs 2.7.2 around Line 16289):

```
            if (opts.labels && opts.labels.usePointStyle) {
                // CHARTJS CODE
            } else if (opts.labels && opts.labels.useLineStyle) {
                if (legendItem.borderDash) {
                    ctx.setLineDash(legendItem.borderDash);
                }
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x, y + fontSize / 2);
                ctx.lineTo(x + boxWidth, y + fontSize / 2);
                ctx.stroke();
            } else {
                // CHARTJS CODE
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

## ChartJS v4

None of the previous answers worked for me. New to chartjs but I think at some point, the schema of their options changed from `options.legend` to `options.plugins.legend`.

According to [their docs for legend labels configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) this should be achievable with the `usePointStyle` and `pointStyle` parameters in the legend labels configuration.

The following code produces this:

[image: Resulting chart]

```js
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My Metric',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                pointStyle: 'line'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    labels: {
                        pointStyle: 'line', // Change to eg 'circle' or 'rect' to control legend independently of the plotted pointStyle
                        usePointStyle: true,
                    }
                }
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make line legend by changing width of legend box (for example 2px), it will be vertical line but it's looks nice too

```
plugins: {
   legend: {
       display: true,
       labels: {
           boxWidth: 2
       }
    }
}
```